# Weird php response

Tags: java, php, android

I'am using AsyncHttp 1.4.4 library, to get data from a php script. On sending a new post request, iam getting a weird response, the response being the source of the page itself. This happens with every time i use asyncHttpClient. I'am not able to figure out why. Please help me resolve this issue.

Php Code:

```
<?php

 echo "1";

?>
```

AsyncHttpClient Object :

```
new AsyncHttpClient().post("http://mywamp.hostei.com/check.php",rp,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(String response)
                 {
                     Log.d("Home","check "+ response);

                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(int code,Throwable t,String err)
                 {
                     Log.d("Home","error "+ err);
                 }
              });
```

LogCat:

```
11-07 20:02:26.212: D/Home(53981429): check 1
11-07 20:02:26.212: D/Home(53981429): &lt!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code --&gt
11-07 20:02:26.212: D/Home(53981429): &ltscript&gt type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"> &lt/script&gt
11-07 20:02:26.212: D/Home(53981429): &lt!-- End Of Analytics Code --&gt
```

Removed some arrows because script tags werent displaying properly.

Comment: "Removed some arrows because script tags werent displaying properly." to avoid this problem post it as code block, or replace `<` with `&lt;`

Comment: @memo Yes..the php script actually exists in my free server mywamp.hostei.com

Comment: Is this a "free hosting" thing where each page has an ad or something injected from the host?

Comment: @mjp66 It a free hosting site.. but theres no ads loading.

Comment: When I loaded http://mywamp.hostei.com/check.php in my browser, the page showed your "1" plus an ad overlaid on top; but when I reload the page, the ad doesn't reappear, still, in the source there's a javascript tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using POST to send your request to this particular page I'd suggest changing the php to something like the following and give that a try:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* clean/empty any output buffers without sending data */
        @ob_clean();

        /* send some data to your async request */
        echo json_encode( array( 'data'=>1, 'time'=>time() ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT  );

        exit(); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are getting the PHP source of the page in the response. It looks like you are just getting the same thing that would be rendered to a browser if you were to load that page in a web browser and click "view source". Did you expect something else to happen here?

It appears that you are getting a `<script>` tag that you aren't expecting in your response, which is causing some confusion. You need to look into what you have configured on your PHP server that is causing that script tag to be added to the response.

Comment: Yes i expect only the "1" returned as response from php script, not the view source code. The other php scripts doesnt do this.

Comment: If you go to that page in a browser, and click "view source" is the script tag there?